# How to import 'wasm' file in the vue application?

Tags: vue.js, webassembly

I want to import my wasm file in the vue component. I have tried different methods but I feel confused. This is all what I have tried -

- I have modified the "vue.config.js" file with option - `chainWebpack` to include my wasm files.
- Then I tried importing wasm but it throws this error - `This is not allowed, because WebAssembly download and compilation must happen asynchronous.Add an async splitpoint (i. e. import()) somewhere between your entrypoint and the WebAssembly module:`

This is my vue.js.config file:
`module.exports = {

```
publicPath: '/',
chainWebpack: webpackConfig => {
    webpackConfig.module
        .rule('wasm')
        .test(/.wasm$/)
        .use('wasm-loader')
        .loader('wasm-loader')
}
```

}'

I compiled my c++ code from here - `https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/`

Can anyone help me? What am I doing wrong here?