# Vue unable to import 'wasm' file

Tags: vue.js, webassembly

How can I import 'wasm' file in my component inside vue. I have been onto this for 2 days and there is no solution. This is my config file :

```
const path = require('path');
const contentBase = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..');

module.exports = {

    assetsDir: 'static',

    configureWebpack: config => {
        config.devServer = {
            before(app) {
                // use proper mime-type for wasm files
                app.get('*.wasm', function (req, res, next) {
                    var options = {
                        root: contentBase,
                        dotfiles: 'deny',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/wasm'
                        }
                    };
                    res.sendFile(req.url, options, function (err) {
                        if (err) { next(err); }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Status code - 404. Even when I'm trying to import the raw 'wasm' file from the folder. Vue is not able to find it. I have been stuck on this for a while now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import 'wasm' file in the vue application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60281678/how-to-import-wasm-file-in-the-vue-application)

Comment: No it does not answer my query. Also the link that you posted is the same question I asked some time back. Desperate times!